# how to cancel web requests using interceptors?

Tags: reactjs

I have a code where I try to make a real world simulation. for this example I want to simulate that I want to make a web request if and **only** if there is a `token` in `localstorage` with the key `"token"`.  The problem is that it executes the amount of web requests that I have running at the moment.

```
const getData = async () => {
 const data = await instance.get("todos/1");
 setData(data.data);
 await instance.get("todos/2");
 await instance.get("todos/3");
};
 .
 .
 .
instance.interceptors.request.use(async (req) => {
token = localStorage.getItem("token") || null;
console.log(req.url);
if (!token) {
  console.log("not exist token");
  //cancel request because token not exists
  return req;
} else {
  console.log("token exist");
  req.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
  return req;
}
});
```

My idea is to cancel or not execute the web requests when there is no token in `localstorage`, and if there is, I would like to send the `token` in the `headers`.

How can I do it?

[this is my live code](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-star-2smn1?file=/src/App.tsx:478-656)

Answer (score 0):

There's a api for request cancellation in axios
https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation

```
const cancelSource = axios.CancelToken.source();

const instance = axios.create({
  cancelToken: cancelSource.token,
  timeout: 1000 * 10,
});

instance.interceptors.request.use((req) => {
  if (condition) {
    cancelSource.cancel('No Authorization Token')
  }
  return req
})
```

BUT, There's much simpler way to abort request.
Just throw an error in the interceptor.

```
instance.interceptors.request.use((req) => {
  if (condition) {
    throw new Error('No Authorization Token')
  }
  return req
})
```

Either of two ways throws Promise Error.
I recommend the latter one, Throwing error.